# Forcing IE into latest rendering engine with meta tag global or single page?

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4, meta-tags

I am attempting to force IE to use the latest rendering engine by applying

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE,chrome=1" />
```

My question is, does this meta tag make any tab in that browser not use compatibility mode, or  is it only applied to the single page the meta tag is applied? I am using MVC 4 and have this meta tag located in my layout page.

Thanks

Comment: haha i was just about to fix the edit myself! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The META tag has nothing to do with MVC, that is server-side. The META tag directs the browser to render that URL using compatibility mode. Edge forces it to use the latest (11 I hope) engines. The META tag, or HTTP Header is that is what you used is tied to the particular URL. If you open the F12 tools you can force IE to a previous version, but that again is tied to the tab and overrides the X-UA-Compatible value and of course has to be done by the end user.